# How do I define a template class and divide it into multiple files?

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, header-files

I have written a simple template class for test purpose. It compiles without any errors, but when I try to use it in main(), it give some linker errors.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyNumber.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    MyNumber<float> num;
    num.SetValue(3.14);
    std::cout << "My number is " << num.GetValue() << "." << std::endl;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**MyNumber.h**

```
#pragma once

template <class T>
class MyNumber
{
    public:
        MyNumber();
        ~MyNumber();
        void SetValue(T val);
        T GetValue();

    private:
        T m_Number;
};
```

**MyNumber.cpp**

```
#include "MyNumber.h"

template <class T>
MyNumber<T>::MyNumber()
{
    m_Number = static_cast<T>(0);
}

template <class T>
MyNumber<T>::~MyNumber()
{
}

template <class T>
void MyNumber<T>::SetValue(T val)
{
    m_Number = val;
}

template <class T>
T MyNumber<T>::GetValue()
{
    return m_Number;
}
```

When I build this code, I get the following linker errors:

> Error 7   Console Demo    C:\Development\IDE\Visual Studio 2010\SAVE\Grand Solution\X64\Debug\Console Demo.exe    1   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
>
> Error 3   Console Demo    C:\Development\IDE\Visual Studio 2010\SAVE\Grand Solution\Console Demo\main.obj error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl MyNumber::~MyNumber(void)" (??1?$MyNumber@M@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function wmain
>
> Error 6   Console Demo    C:\Development\IDE\Visual Studio 2010\SAVE\Grand Solution\Console Demo\main.obj error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl MyNumber::MyNumber(void)" (??0?$MyNumber@M@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function wmain
>
> Error 4   Console Demo    C:\Development\IDE\Visual Studio 2010\SAVE\Grand Solution\Console Demo\main.obj error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __cdecl MyNumber::GetValue(void)" (?GetValue@?$MyNumber@M@@QEAAMXZ) referenced in function wmain
>
> Error 5   Console Demo    C:\Development\IDE\Visual Studio 2010\SAVE\Grand Solution\Console Demo\main.obj error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl MyNumber::SetValue(float)" (?SetValue@?$MyNumber@M@@QEAAXM@Z) referenced in function wmain

But, if I leave main() empty, I don't get any linker errors.

What is wrong with my template class?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate your template explicitly for each template parameter you use.

I.e., add the following line at the end of the `MyNumber.cpp` file:

```
template class MyNumber<float>;
```

This way, the linker will be able to find all template instantiations it needs.

See also [Moving Templates Out of Header Files](http://www.drdobbs.com/moving-templates-out-of-header-files/184403420).

Answer (score 1):

You can not implement the template in a cpp file. You need to define the class methods in the header file itself. See this [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) for more information.

Comment: I knew that template methods must be defined only in header files. Is that the same for template classes?

Comment: Yes, it is same for classes also, unless your compiler supports `export` key word (which would be rare in my experience)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're actually supposed to be able to use the [export](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.14) keyword, but almost no compilers implement it. You can work around this by extracting non-generic code into separate functions, and define these in separate files.